# How to add the search option for a tableview in ios 9 using uisearchcontroller, with objectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I have a tableView that displays data successfully and now what I want is to provide the search function for it. UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 9 and I'm new to iOS. So please tell me the way to do this.
If anyone can provide a code step by step,I appreciate it and it will also help others.This is my tableView code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [airportList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ci"];

    Details *newDetails = [airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = newDetails.airport;

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Details *newDetails = [airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectedText = newDetails.airport;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selectedText forKey:@"st"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I found this tutorial very helpful https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `UISearchController` in iOS 9

First declare a property for `UISearchController`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
```

then, in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

When creating the `UISearchController` we do not need a separate search results controller as we will use the `UITableViewController` itself.
Likewise we will also use the `UITableViewController` to update the search results by having it implement the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol.
We do not want to dim the underlying content as we want to show the filtered results as the user types into the search bar.
The `UISearchController` takes care of creating the search bar for us.
The `UITableViewController` will also act as the search bar delegate for when the user changes the search scope.

Next, add `searchBar` to tableview header

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Since the search view covers the table view when active we make the `UITableViewController` define the presentation context:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

We need to implement the `UISearchResultsUpdating` delegate to generate the new filtered results anytime the search text changes:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
  NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
  [self searchForText:searchString scope:searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @Graham, it is custom method I used to create a filtered list based on predicates. You can write your own with predicates that you need.

Comment: @Graham , hope that helped . Please up vote if it really helped.

Comment: Awesome..Thanks for the answer

Comment: Excellent answer - should be marked at the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @yogi did you declare searchForText somewhere else? it seems when i try to implement your solution i need to declare it somewhere.

Comment: @m00ncake yes, you need to declare it.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn with Apple Sample Guide：[Table Search with UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014683-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

`“Table Search with UISearchController”` is an iOS sample application that demonstrates how to use `UISearchController`. A search controller manages the presentation of a search bar (in concert with the results view controller’s content).

Comment: Link "Table Search with UISearchController" is for iOS 10 or later. There is no good example on this pages for iOS 9